# Obtaining latLng of cursor/mouse when triggered by a PolyMouseEvent

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to the Google Maps API... so I apologize in advance if the answer to this question is somewhat basic... I have spent several hours trying to find a solution.

**Explanation:**

I would like to show an infowindow at the point the cursor was at when a click was detected while in a polygon.

I am able to open the infowindow - but am unable to determine the location to use.

It appears that the PolyMouseEvent object does not allow for getting the latLng like the MouseEvent does.

Is there a way to the the current mouse position (in latLng) in this case?

Comment: Also - new to stackoverflow - so my rep is a bit low (non-existent)... Looking around for things to answer and help a bit myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set clickable:false in the PolygonOptions and listen for the click event on the map itself.